How to add the autolot that for every 1000 on the budget adds 0.01 on this code in MQL4
I tried to add this functionality that for every 1000$ adds 0.01 but it continuously gives me problems, the functionality that checks lots is called in multiple parts of the code because it uses a lotstep to make a martingale so I am not understanding how to solve this problem.
Also as I'm sending it to you it doesn't work well, it doesn't do the martingale and only opens 0.01 per 1000
double Expert::lotAdjust(string sym, double lots)
  {
   double value = 0;
   double lotStep = SymbolInfoDouble(sym,SYMBOL_VOLUME_STEP);
   double minLot  = SymbolInfoDouble(sym,SYMBOL_VOLUME_MIN);
   double maxLot  = SymbolInfoDouble(sym,SYMBOL_VOLUME_MAX);
   
 // Calculate the auto lot based on account balance
   double accountBalance = AccountBalance();
   double autoLots = (accountBalance / 1000.0) * 0.01;

   // Normalize the lot size according to the step size
   value = NormalizeDouble(autoLots / lotStep, 0) * lotStep;
  
   if(value < minLot)
      value = minLot;
   if(value > maxLot)
      value = maxLot;

   return(value);
  }


 buyLot = lotAdjust(sym,BuyPriceMinLot * MathPow(nextLot,buys));
 selLot = lotAdjust(sym,SelPriceMaxLot * MathPow(nextLot,sells));

